# it throws a 404 when without url prefix (FLASK)

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, web, url

You see Im having a problem where in flask, I made a web app. and I added the URL prefix as views
and you see without /views attached to localhost it throws a 404, I wanna change it so it will redirect automatically to /views when you go to the regular URL such as http://127.0.0.1:8000/

I tried adding @app.route in app.py but it just caused even more problems

Comment: If code it needed please just comment and say that you need my code to get an understanding of the error/problem Im having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could redirect automatically from  http://127.0.0.1:8000/ to  http://127.0.0.1:8000/views using the code below.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)

#Page 1
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def welcome():
  return redirect("http://127.0.0.1:8000/views", code=302)

#Page 2
@app.route('/views', methods=['GET'])
def hello():
  return jsonify({"data": "Hello"})

if __name__ == '__main__':
 app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port="8000")
```

**Output**

```
 #127.0.0.1 - - [01/Dec/2022 15:23:23] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 - (Redirecting to views page)
 #127.0.0.1 - - [01/Dec/2022 15:23:23] "GET /views HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Hope this helps. Happy Coding :)

Comment: I just tried that, but can you specify what folder to put that code in? I put it in app.py and it said site cant be reached

Comment: Thank you so much, your code worked. And now it redirects when i put it whoithout the prefix